# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Carousel - Exception in MessageQueue callback and handleReceiveCallback

Tags: android, carousel

I am using carousel in my app.

For users having Android 4.2.2 and only in Landscape mode they are reporting this issue:

```
12-19 15:01:56.685: E/InputEventReceiver(7009): Exception dispatching input event.
12-19 15:01:56.685: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2076)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at com.digitalaria.gama.carousel.CarouselBehavior.dispatchTouchEvent(CarouselBehavior.java:1768)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2284)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1578)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2468)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2232)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7876)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3894)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3778)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5030)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5009)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5107)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
12-19 15:01:56.695: E/MessageQueue-JNI(7009):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am unable to find what is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're storing your `Views` in an array.

When the device is rotated, this array is reset and all the views are removed. When the array adapter is trying to get its position, because the array is empty, it returns `-1`.

Try handle the rotation event and make sure you repopulate the array.

I can't answer for sure without seeing some code, but it definitely looks like the array/list of views is being emptied or set to null.

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1, the array is not empty, the length is 12.  But something is trying to access the index -1, which doesn't exist, ever.